# How to get parameter from Controller method in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have tried following way to use of routes and controller and tried to get parameter values from the controller method but I get result $1. but actually, I passed 3.

```
routes.php
    $route['helloword/:any'] = "FirstProgram/helloworld/$1";

    controller
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class FirstProgram extends CI_Controller {
      public function helloworld($param=''){
        $data = array(
          'title'   => 'Title',
          'heading' => 'Heading',
          'message' => 'Message',
          'param'   => $param
        );
        echo $param;exit;
        $this->load->view('FirstProgram', $data);
      }
    }
    ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your route code just add a bracket for :any

```
$route['helloword/(:any)'] = "FirstProgram/helloworld/$1";
```